# QT - Custom Delegate in multi hierarchy tree

Tags: qt

I have a multi hierarchy QTreeView (currently 3 levels, will be more depends),
    I created 3 different delegates for each level
    But how do I apply the delegate to the QTreeView properly?
    The following pic shows what I want:

```
>Row 0 -------------------- delegate A
>Row 1 -------------------- delegate A

^Row 2 -------------------- delegate A
  ^Row 20 ----------------- delegate B
     Row 200 -------------- delegate C
     Row 201 -------------- delegate C
     Row 202 -------------- delegate C

  ^Row 21 ----------------- delegate B
     Row 210 -------------- delegate C
     Row 211 -------------- delegate C
     Row 212 -------------- delegate C

This function:
    QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForRow(int row, QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate);

With this function, I can only assign the delegate for the first level of the TreeView.
And its children (level 2, level 3) are gonna share the same delegate with level 1
```

How do I assign the delegate B to Row 20 and Row 21?
How do I assign delegate C to Row 200, Row 201, Row 202......

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible the way you are trying to accomplish it. Instead, I suggest that you assign a common delegate to all items and inside the handler choose different paths based on the row/column index. Could be a bit of a mess though.

Comment: 1. This is a dynamic tree, so It could be super messy. .
2. How do I get the access of the sub row?
For row2 I can write:
if (Index.row() == 2)
But for row20 and Row 200 and Row201,
They share the same row index.....

Comment: @btbt9527, How to access the tree elements will depend on the model that you are using. Here is a good example of how to build a good tree model: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html